# PTIJ: What sort of Yid is Mr. Black?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Here's what we know about [Mr. Black](https://seuss.fandom.com/wiki/Mr._Black), from Dr Seuss's *Hop on Pop*:

- He has a frock, black hat, and beard. ([image](https://www.pistilbooks.net/assets/images/product/142027b.jpg))
- He comes back from "out of town" with Mr. Brown; implying Mr. Black lives outside of New York. ([image](https://www.pistilbooks.net/assets/images/product/142027b.jpg))
- He eats a "snack" with Mr. Brown and Pup that includes a sandwich, which means he must hold of "mezonos bread". ([image](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e3/88/99/e38899ecd4805d0a4458ebb99fa45b4f--snack-pack-graham-crackers.jpg))

He seems pretty frum, but how many frum Jews live "out of town" anyways? And the consensus of poskim is against mezonos bread *[citation needed]*. What subgroup could he possibly belong to?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: For future reference, Purim Torah questions only use the purim-torah-in-jest tag and require "PTIJ:" in the title. You can see the full policy [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/purim-torah-policy-allowed-but-regulated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For someone who loves to hop on Pop, he has to be a "Poppa" Chassid. These are a branch of the Puppa Chassidim that was named after the town Papa in Hungary.

The "Poppa" Hassidm have the same dress and customs as the Puppa Chassidim. The only differences is that they pronounce the vowel "U" as "o" and they have round hands and claws on their feet.